# Creating an empty collection view cell throws error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using `UICollectionView` with custom `UICollectionViewCell`.

I create an empty cell using :

```
[[MyCell alloc] init];
```

and compiler throws error :

```
Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:]
```

I tried below in `viewDidLoad:` method :

```
[self.collection registerClass:[MyCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
```

Then in `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method :

```
MyCell *cell = [[MyCell alloc] init];
```

Comment: This may occurred because you are not using any kind of `reuseIdentifier`

Comment: @Morpheus So what you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You must tell the collection view how to create the corresponding view if one does not already exist. For this, you must register either a class or a nib file with the collection view.Use any one of these methods

```
- (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass forCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
- (void)registerClass:(Class)viewClass forSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)elementKind withReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)kind withReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
```

[Go through this portion for more details](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012177-CH1-SW56)

Comment: I added `[self.collection registerClass:[MyCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];` in `viewDidLoad:` but still crashing with that same error. I have created this cell in storyboard and have class for it.

Answer (score 0):

In implementation file make a constant `NSString` identifier.

```
static NSString * const CustomClassCellIdentifier = @"Cell";
```

then in `viewDidLoad:`

```
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomClassCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CustomClassCellIdentifier];

//[self.collectionView registerClass:[CustomClassCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CustomClassCellIdentifier];
```

Then in `dataSource` Method

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomClassCell *customCell =
        [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CustomClassCellIdentifier
                  forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return customCell;
}
```

Comment: I need empty cell. Using `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:` will give cell with some values already set.

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: edited answer now check, if you are using nib file for customCell